# How many times does Sam's rope save the day?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

During The Lord of the Rings I've noticed that Sam Gamgee goes on about his old Gaffer talking about ropes and he gets excited when rope is mentioned. How many time throughout the three books does this trusty rope save the day?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recall twice when it used in the book:

- To get down the cliff in the Emyn Muil.  It also glowed slightly in the dark, allowing Frodo to find it after falling so you might count that separately.
- To bind Gollum after his capture.

Comment: yeah, the freaking dirt was more impressive/useful in the end.

Comment: But if they hadn't had the rope, the dirt wouldn't have done any good because they might not have completed their mission and thus gotten back to the Shire for them to use the dirt

Comment: The dirt was also a gift from Galadrial.  IIRC Sam just nicked the rope from the bottom of the boat.

Comment: Were there other times where he didn't have a rope but needed one?

Comment: Yep, in Moria - "There were fissures and chasms in the walls and floor, and every now and then a crack would open right before their feet. The widest was more than seven feet across, and it was long before Pippin could summon enough courage to leap over the dreadful gap. The noise of churning water came up from far below, as if some great mill-wheel was turning in the depths. 'Rope!' muttered Sam. 'I knew I'd want it, if I hadn't got it!'"

Comment: You never go on an adventure without rope and a ten foot pole...